# Change audio pitch based on rigidbody speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We have some sound for when the player is moving or rolling being the player is a ball. We want to increase the pitch of the audio the faster the ball goes. I tried the below code but it doesn't do anything. I think it's because the value of p comes out too small.
I remember reading somewhere that there is something built in to handle this but I can't think of where I saw or it what it was called.

Thanks in advance!

```
     void FixedUpdate()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_STANDALONE
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
         Vector3 move = new Vector3(-moveHorizontal, 0.0f, -moveVertical);            
        move = move * (speed / 15f);
        //maxSpeed = maxSpeed / 5;
#else
        // Player movement in mobile devices
        // Building of force vector             
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(-Input.acceleration.x, 0.0f, -Input.acceleration.y);
        // Adding force to rigidbody
        move = move * (speed / 15f);
        //move = movement * speed * Time.deltaTime;            
#endif
        rigidbdy.AddForce(move);
        var p = rigidbdy.velocity.magnitude / speed;
        audio.pitch = Mathf.Clamp(p, 1.0f, 2.0f); // p is clamped to sane values

        //Limits the max speed
        if (rigidbdy.velocity.magnitude > maxSpeed)
        {
            rigidbdy.velocity = rigidbdy.velocity.normalized * maxSpeed;               
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`map`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/map) function for easy control over the pitch value.

```
float mapValue(float mainValue, float inValueMin, float inValueMax, float outValueMin, float outValueMax)
{
    return (mainValue - inValueMin) * (outValueMax - outValueMin) / (inValueMax - inValueMin) + outValueMin;
}
```

---

You pass in `AudioSource.pitch` to the `mainValue` parameter.

---

For the `inValueMin` value, you pass in the default/MIN value of the `Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude` which is `0`.

---

For the `inValueMax` value, you pass in the MAX value your ball can go.
You can easily determine this number with `Debug.Log("RB: " + ballRigidbody.velocity.magnitude);` and running the game. `10` seems to be fine for this. You must determine your own value.

---

The default `AudioSource.pitch` value is `1`, so `outValueMin` parameter should  be `1`.

---

The `outValueMax` parameter will be the maximum pitch you think is acceptable to you. I found `1.5` to be ok for this so `1.5` will be used for `outValueMax`.

---

Whatever you get from the `mapValue` function is what you assign to the `AudioSource.pitch`. This gives you much more control over the pitch of you sound. You can read more about this function on the Arduino [site](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/map).

Remove your current Audio code and replace it  with this:

```
float rigidBodyMangintude = rigidbdy.velocity.magnitude;
float pitch = mapValue(rigidBodyMangintude, 0f, 10f, 1f, 1.5f);

audio.pitch = pitch;
Debug.Log("Pitch: " + pitch);
```

The `mapValue` function is at the top of this answer.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try later today and report back.